# jquery regex replace everything after first appearance of match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i want to replace everything after the first match of `Stk.`
Used this but its not working: `text.replace('/(Stk\.).*/','')`

Example String (**the string is two-lines**):

```
123456 50 Stk.
test Stk.
```

I want to delete `test Stk.`, so everything after `the first Stk.`

Comment: maybe use `split`.
var new_text = text.split('Stk')[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove single quotes from around the regex literal, use `[\s\S]` to match any char and a backreference in the replacement pattern:

```js
var text = "123456 50 Stk.\ntest Stk.";
console.log(text.replace(/(Stk\.)[\s\S]*/,'$1'));
```

**Details**:

- `(Stk\.)` - capturing group 1 matching `Stk.` substring and storing it inside a memory buffer the contents of which can be accessed with `$1` backreference from the string replacement pattern
- `[\s\S]*` - matches any 0 or more characters, as many as possible (so, up to the end of the whole string, multiline or not).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @azmd108: Note that `splitting` solution might be a more natural and readable  solution. Or a solution based on `substr()`/`substring()` as your `Stk.` delimiter is a literal string. I just focused on fixing your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function.

```js
var string = "123456 50 Stk.\n test Stk."
var result = string.split('Stk');
console.log(result[0]);
```